# How to convert a raw element (CSV) to a dataset?

Tags: r

Im scraping a ASP.NET website.

This will return a raw element (`reporte_nacido`) which is a csv file:

```
reporte_nacido = postForm('https://xxxxx/WebSiteNDE/BirthsPages/FiltrosExcelNac.aspx',
                               .params = params, 
                               curl = curl,
                               .opts = RCurl::curlOptions(ssl.verifypeer=FALSE, verbose=T))
```

Im currently writing that raw file on disk with this line

```
writeBin( as.vector(unlist(reporte_nacido)) , "file.csv" )
```

Instead of having to write in disk, i would like to use the initial raw element (`reporte_nacido`) and convert it to a dataframe inside R since i require to do some data prep here.

Would that be possible?

EDIT
After trying some options, im seeing an extra issue:

```
> read.csv(text=rawToChar(as.vector(unlist(reporte_nacido))))
Error in rawToChar(as.vector(unlist(reporte_nacido))) : 
  embedded nul in string:  '\xfe\xff\0N\0\xda\0M\0E\0R\0O\0 \0C\0E\0R\0T\0I\0F\0I\0C\0A\0D\0O\0\t\0D\0E\0P\0A\0R\0T\0A\0M\0E\0N\0T\0O\0\t\0M\0U\0N\0I\0C\0I\0P\0I\0O\0\t\0A\0R\0E\0A\0 \0N\0A\0C\0I\0M\0I\0E\0N\0T\0O\0\t\0I\0N\0S\0P\0E\0C\0C\0I\0O\0N\0 \0C\0O\0R\0R\0E\0G\0I\0M\0I\0E\0N\0T\0O\0 \0O\0 \0C\0A\0S\0E\0R\0I\0O\0 \0N\0A\0C\0I\0M\0I\0E\0N\0T\0O\0\t\0S\0I\0T\0I\0O\0 \0N\0A\0C\0I\0M\0I\0E\0N\0T\0O\0\t\0C\0\xd3\0D\0I\0G\0O\0 \0I\0N\0S\0T\0I\0T\0U\0C\0I\0\xd3\0N\0\t\0N\0O\0M\0B\0R\0E\0 \0I\0N\0S\0T\0I\0T\0U\0C\0I\0\xd3\0N\0\t\0S\0E\0X\0O\0\t\0P\0E\0S\0O\0 \0(\0G\0r\0a\0m\0o\0s\0)\0\t\0T\0A\0L\0L\0A\0 \0(\0C\0e\0n\0t\0\xed\0m\0e\0t\0r\0o\0s\0)\0\t\0F\0E\0C\0H\0A\0 \0N\0A\0C\0I\0M\0I\0E\0N\0T\0O\0\t\0H\0O\0R\0A\0 \0N\0A\0C\0I\0M\0I\0E\0N\0T\0O\0\t\0P\0A\0R\0T\0O\0 \0A\0T\0E\0N\0D\0I\0D\0O\0 \0P\0O\0R\0\t\0T\0I\0E\0M\0P\0O\0 \0D\0E\0 \0G\0E\0S\0T\0A\0C\0I\0\xd3\0N\0\t\0N\0\xda\0M\0E\0R\0O\0 \0C\0O\0N\0S\0U\0L\0T\0A\0S\0 \0P\0R\0E\0N\0A\0T\0A\0L\0E\0S\0\t\0T\0I\0P\0O\0 \0P\0A
```

Comment: Without testing, try `read_excel(rawConnection(x))` where `x` is the `raw` data. (I don't know if it's work, but `rawConnection` would be the way to do it without writing to files, if such a method exists.)

Comment: Maybe `read.csv(text=rawToChar(as.vector(unlist(reporte_nacido))))`?

Comment: please see adendum in question